# xelatex conditional compiling

Tags: xetex, compiling

I want to compile the same tex file with different options set at compile time. Minimal example : bare.tex

```
\documentclass{article}
    \begin{document}
    \ifx\myclass\undefined
        Myclass was undefined
    \else
        Myclass is \myclass
    \fi
\end{document}
```

I compile with

```
xelatex bare "\def\myclass{56}"
```

Result is

[image]

Of course I'd like to have "Myclass is 56", what is wrong ?

Comment: Try `xelatex "\def\myclass{56}\input bare"`

Comment: In addition, maybe `\ifcsname myclass\endcsname
        Myclass is \myclass
    \else
        Myclass was undefined
    \fi` is more robust.

Answer (score 1):

If you call `xelatex -help` from the command line you get

```
> xelatex --help
Usage: xetex [OPTION]... [TEXNAME[.tex]] [COMMANDS]
   or: xetex [OPTION]... \FIRST-LINE
   or: xetex [OPTION]... &FMT ARGS
  Run XeTeX on TEXNAME, usually creating TEXNAME.pdf.
  Any remaining COMMANDS are processed as XeTeX input, after TEXNAME is read.
  If the first line of TEXNAME is %&FMT, and FMT is an existing .fmt file,
  use it.  Else use `NAME.fmt', where NAME is the program invocation name,
  most commonly `xetex'.
```

What the text *doesn't* say is that `COMMANDS` are inserted *after* the main file `TEXNAME` has been read in. For instance, the following document `test.tex`

```
a
```

upon a call such as

```
xetex test "b\bye"
```

will produce

[image]

but changing `test.tex` into

```
a\bye
```

will only print an “a”, because `b\bye` will be read in *after* the `\bye` in the document, so ignored.

The same happens with your call: the input `\def\myclass{56}` is inserted after `\end{document}`, so it does nothing at all.

You want to use the other feature:

```
xelatex '\def\myclass{56}\input{bare}'
```

(I prefer single quotes, but it's personal opinion). Since `bare.tex` is the first file that's input, the job name will be correctly set.